# Text file busy when trying to execute sql file via python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to execute python using bash that functions to execute a created sql file.

The python code is like this:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='skynetadmin',
                         password='Skynetadmin1',
                         host='silmysskytest01.sing.micron.com',
                         database='skynet_msa')
cursor =cnx.cursor()

def executeScriptsFromFile('Creation of Lab WIP History.sql'):
fd = open('Creation of Lab WIP History.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()
sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

for command in sqlCommands:
    try:
        if command.strip() != '':
            cursor.execute(command)
    except IOError, msg:
        print "Command skipped: ", msg

executeScriptsFromFile('C:\Users\gsumarlin\Documents\dumps\Dump20220428')
cnx.commit()
```

However, the message I got after running it in bash is: Text file busy.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This error means you are trying to modify an executable while it is executing. The "Text" here refers to the fact that the file being modified is the text segment for a running program. Use lsof to check what other processes are using it. You can use kill command to kill it if needed.

Comment: i have windows so i do not know how to lsof. sb suggested using nestnet but even then im still not sure what i am reading. whats the command to kill command then?